# Have pages of a separate document not count into \getpagerefnumber{LastPage}

Tags: header-footer, count

I want to put a release document before my actual document. Currently I am doing this by using

```
  \input{"../Common Subdocuments/Documents/ReleaseDocument"}
```

The problem that arises is the new page count. My footer contains a line with this code:

```
Page~\thepage~of~\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}
```

I do not want the release document to count. Of course I could compile the document separately and merge those 2 together afterwards but I was wondering if there is a command that makes pages not count.

Comment: Please provide some example documents that are compilable, not just a *feature* request!

Comment: You can reset the page counter after loading the release page. `\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}`

Comment: do you just want the total to change or do you want to reset the page counter back to 1 after your insert?

Comment: Using `xassoccnt` package it's possible to suspend a counter (here the page counter) and resume it afterwards.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Both.

Comment: @Christian Huper: Thanks, I will check that out.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: This works well, but leaves the total number of pages too high. The 2 pages before the document are still counted.

Comment: @gentlesea if you reset the counter to 1 then there is nothing more to do the last page count is just the page number of the last page. (it may take a couple of latex runs to settle down)

Comment: Not in my testfile. LastPage reports the number of the last page, not the totalcount.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer your answer, it seems:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the page counter after loading the release page.

```
  \newpage\setcounter{page}{1}
```